# Regular Expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get all the numbers that start with #.

"this is sentence 1 . Item number #4567 "

"this is sentence 2. Item number #8937  and #6723"

I am using JavaScript.

Using regular expression how do I get all the numbers in a string.

Answer (score 10):

```
var matches = "Item number #8937 and #6723".match(/#\d+/g);
print(matches[0]);   // #8937
print(matches[1]);   // #6723
```

Comment: I would vote the answer up, but it's too easy to deserve a vote I think.

Comment: @darkporter: That's perfectly good with me. Your vocal "vote" of confidence is very much appreciated. :-)

Comment: I can have 1 or 10 such numbers. It is not limited to 2.